# Node.js & Three.js - Reduce Client Workload

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, three.js, gis

EDITED
Rewrote the whole question:I need to update parts of large stream network data (stream flow parameters per line segment, ca. 120.000 segments) in realtime (each hour). The data will be exported from remote DB as topojson (3d lines with height per vertex) to visualize flow parameters as moving particles per segment (with particle emitters on vertices) draped on high-res DEM (800.000 vertices).
Node.js runs as server (localhost) on client computer, connects to remote DB for data updates and hosts the animation via firefox continuously until the end of time (this setting is asked for...can't change much).
I know my way around most things here, but I lack knowledge of actual client/server communications when it comes to data flow and the experience with three.js.
I need to avoid hiccups as much as possible and thought about making most of the data preparation (getting data, format json, create geometries, do statistics on flow params, etc.) on server side and push the data (perhaps even the three.js geometeies) to the client once preparation is ready.
How to do that (REST, streaming, websocket...), what would be good practice here? And would that increase performance for client rendering (the machine is not high end) with three.js when I reduce browser-side calculations?

Need some general direction, hints, maybe you know exactly how to implement it, maybe you know some good article to point me at for me to learn.

Thanks!

Comment: more details would definitely be appreciated since right now i have no idea what you're talking about :) wonder if someone else does. Why did some objects fail to be sent? Are you trying to avoid hiccups when loading new data? Dont think theres anything to gain by doing "heavy lifting" on the server, actually on the contrary you might suffer some penalties when parsing an unpacked mesh depending on how you do it (streaming would help though).

Comment: thanks, yes I see that now. I tried to specify a little. but you got some of my problems...

Comment: rewrote the whole question...

Comment: Uh, it's a bit complicated. You need to understand what those calculations entail. You can also fire up a worker to do some mesh parsing, creation etc in a separate thread. It's also worth getting familiar with the rendering pipeline, there is a stage when you upload the data to the gpu, and that can take a hit. It is possible to do this in small chunks, as to not stall the rendering. Either way, this wouldnt be done on the server.

Comment: @pailhead I had to do other things first, sorry for not replying...and a late thanks for your comment! I was thinking about increasing performance on the actual GL part of this...but as a last resort, due to what I know about it. no, stay with me on the dummy-side of my question: I thought it a clean solution to just set up a renderer and the scene on the client js and push all my pre-built meshes etc. to it when they are ready. you actually helped me with saying that meshes might be uncompressed (as I thougth the opposite) and streaming would help!